# FormArray and AsyncValidators (not AsyncValicatorFn)

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a FormArray of controls. The primary use case of this is for a user to paste in a list of values, the application splits the values one line breaks, and then creates as many inputs as needed in the FormArray and assigns the value to each one. The user can also add controls one by one and input the values manually, but this will be a rare exception, not the rule.

What I want to do is validate that ALL the pasted values are valid compared to master data with a single call to the server of an array of the supplied values in the array. What I can't seem to figure out is how to assign an AsyncValidator (NOT an AsyncValidatorFn) to a FormArray. The FormBuilder only takes AsyncValidatorFn (or an array of them). Since there's no element to assign the directive to for the AsyncValidator, it's unclear to me how this should work. I could do something silly like inject the validator into the parent component, and then use `setValidator` on the FormArray, but that sure seems hacky. There's surely a better way, right?

e.g. User pastes following (imagine copying a column of values from excel)

```
1
2
3
4
```

Angular app splits that into 4 values and assigns each to it's own input in the Form Array.

FormArray AsyncValidator calls server endpoint with an argument of [1,2,3,4] and from there the ValidationErrors are generated as necessary.

Comment: Post some code. This seems pretty straightforward although I have no idea what your issue is between AsyncValidator and AsyncValidatorFn..?

Comment: I figured it out. I was previously unaware of the `formArrayName` directive. Using that I can structure my AsyncValidator as a directive and apply it to the same element.  e.g. `<ng-container formArrayName="lookupvalues" appValuesExistValidator>`. Super easy.

Answer (score 0):

I had 2 issues:

1. I got hung up on adding the validators via the `FormBuilder` rather than as directives.
2. I didn't know about the `formArrayName` directive

I created the `ValuesExistValidator` as a directive and added it to an `<ng-container` element with a `formControlName` directive so angular could apply it to that FormArray

```
<ng-container formControlName="lookupvalues" appValuesExistValidator>
  <!-- inputs here -->
</ng-container>
```

Works perfectly.